# solving two dimensional diffusion advection equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I know that the solution to one dimensional diffusion advection equation is easy to obtain. However, was wondering if the same is true for two dimensional linear diffusion advection equation, i.e.,

$$ \frac{\partial \phi(x,y,t)}{\partial t} + v_x \frac{\partial \phi(x,y,t)}{\partial x} + v_y \frac{\partial \phi(x,y,t)}{\partial y} = D_x \frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,y,t)}{\partial x^2} + D_y \frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,y,t)}{\partial y^2},$$ for $0 \le x, y \le \infty$

where, $v_x, v_y, D_x, D_y$ are constants in time and space.

In particular the solution of above equation for initial conditions, $\phi(x,y,0) = f_1(x) \delta(y)+f_2(y)\delta(x)$, i.e., all of the material is confined to $x$ and $y$ axis respectively (I hope I got it right in mathematical form). The boundary conditions are reflective, i.e., zero flux at the boundary.

I am also interested in knowing and understanding, if above equation will give rise to two dimensional exponential profile or not in equilibrium.

Thanks

Comment: If the $v_{i}$ and $D_{i}$ are just constants, then make a change of argument (for lack of a better description)

$$\phi(x,y,t) = f(x - v_{x}t, y - v_{y}t, t) = f(p, q, t)$$

and apply the chain rule to find $\phi_{x}, \phi_{y}, \phi_{t}$ etc in terms of $f$. You should find that the first order spatial derivatives are eliminated and your equation should then become

$$f_{t} = D_{1} f_{pp} + D_{2} f_{qq}$$

which is just the 2D diffusion equation.